# SWUpdate RootFS and Device Tree

Tags: embedded-linux, yocto, swupdate

I am using Yocto to create a Linux build for an IMX6. This is going great and I am not looking into using [SWUpdate](https://sbabic.github.io/swupdate/index.html) to perform kernel and device tree updates. So far I have a bitbake script which does the following.

```
source setup-environment build-fb/
bitbake -c cleanall swupdate
bitbake swupdate
bitbake -c cleanall swupdate-image
bitbake swupdate-image
bitbake -c cleanall mainapplication-dev
bitbake mainapplication-dev
bitbake -c cleanall smg-image-swu
bitbake smg-image-swu
```

This properly configures my build and creates a `.swu` file containing three items

1. mainapplication-dev-imx6ull14x14evk.tar.bz2
2. sw-description
3. update.sh

I followed a guide by [Variscite](https://variwiki.com/index.php?title=SWUpdate_Guide) and referenced their [GitHub](https://github.com/varigit/meta-variscite-sdk/blob/1b48fd1e26b71fa85efbee97a2325cd78512c856/dynamic-layers/swupdate/var-image-swupdate.bb). In their guide they mention that [image]

This leads me to believe that after they run a build, the `.swu` file contains the files I listed above with the addition that in `/boot` lies a `zimage` and a `.dtb` file. I have replicated their `bb` files. In my `mainapplication-dev-imx6ull14x14evk.tar.bz2` in the `/boot` directory, I only have a `zimage`. I cannot get this to package the device tree.

Has anyone done this before? Can anyone guide me here? For reference I am adding my bitbake files below.

smg-image-swu.bb:

```
DESCRIPTION = "Example compound image for Variscite boards"
SECTION = ""

# Note: sw-description is mandatory
SRC_URI = " \
    file://sw-description \
    file://update.sh \
"

inherit swupdate

LICENSE = "MIT"
LIC_FILES_CHKSUM = "file://${COMMON_LICENSE_DIR}/MIT;md5=0835ade698e0bcf8506ecda2f7b4f302"

# IMAGE_DEPENDS: list of Yocto images that contains a root filesystem
# it will be ensured they are built before creating swupdate image
IMAGE_DEPENDS = "mainapplication-dev"

# SWUPDATE_IMAGES: list of images that will be part of the compound image
# the list can have any binaries - images must be in the DEPLOY directory
SWUPDATE_IMAGES = "mainapplication-dev"

SWUPDATE_IMAGES_FSTYPES[mainapplication-dev] = ".tar.bz2"
```

smg-image-swupdate.bb

```
DESCRIPTION = ""
LICENSE = "MIT"

require recipes-core/images/core-image-minimal.bb

CORE_IMAGE_EXTRA_INSTALL += " \
    swupdate \
    swupdate-www \
    kernel-image \
    kernel-devicetree \
"

IMAGE_FSTYPES = "tar.gz"
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To add the device tree and modules to my `.swu` image I made the following change to smg-image-swu.bb

```
DESCRIPTION = "Example compound image for Variscite boards"
SECTION = ""

# Note: sw-description is mandatory
SRC_URI = " \
    file://sw-description \
    file://update.sh \
"

inherit swupdate

LICENSE = "MIT"
LIC_FILES_CHKSUM = "file://${COMMON_LICENSE_DIR}/MIT;md5=0835ade698e0bcf8506ecda2f7b4f302"

# IMAGE_DEPENDS: list of Yocto images that contains a root filesystem
# it will be ensured they are built before creating swupdate image
IMAGE_DEPENDS = "mainapplication-dev virtual/kernel"

# SWUPDATE_IMAGES: list of images that will be part of the compound image
# the list can have any binaries - images must be in the DEPLOY directory
SWUPDATE_IMAGES = "mainapplication-dev \
            modules-imx6ull14x14evk \
            imx6ull-14x14-evk"

SWUPDATE_IMAGES_FSTYPES[mainapplication-dev] = ".tar.bz2"
SWUPDATE_IMAGES_FSTYPES[modules-imx6ull14x14evk] = ".tgz"
SWUPDATE_IMAGES_FSTYPES[imx6ull-14x14-evk] = ".dtb"
```